# What are the methods for solving analytically an coupled system of second order linear PDEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

What are the methods for solving analytically an coupled system of second order linear PDE? (As I know we can solve by transforming to linear ODEs system. What else?)

If you suggest some books or notes in order to learn to solving coupled system of second-order linear PDEs, I'm very pleased, your suggestions are very important for me.